# Autogenerate GraphQL API interface

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, apollo-client

I'm using Apollo to access a GraphQL endpoint. I have the complete schema in a file. Suppose that the schema is as follows:

```
type Widget {
    widgetId: ID!
    name: String
}

type Query {
    listWidgets: [Widget!]!
}

type Mutation {
    updateWidget(
        widgetId: ID!
        name: String
    ): Widget!
}
```

I would like to create an API object with an interface like so:

```js
const api = MyApi(endpoint);

const widgets = await api.listWidgets();

const modifiedWidget = await api.updateWidget({
    widgetId: 'myId',
    name: 'My widget',
});
```

Is there an existing system that does this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far the strongest thing I am seeing in my research is [graphql-sequelize](https://github.com/mickhansen/graphql-sequelize), which is a graphql database backend for the Sequelize interface, one of Node.js's more popular ORMs currently.